# Solve a linear system of equations in R

Tags: r, matrix

I don’t know how to proceed in the following case because the last equation doesn’t have all the 4 variables. So used the code below the equation, but this is wrong... Does anyone know the way to proceed?

Euqations:

```
3a + 4b - 5c + d = 10

2a + 2b + 2c - d = 5

a -b + 5c - 5d = 7

5a + d = 4
```

Code:

```
 X <- matrix(c(3,4,-5,1,2,2,2,-1,1,-1,5,-5,5,0,0,1), 4, 4)
 y <- matrix(c(10,5,7,4), 4, 1)
 solve(X)%*%y #equivalent to solve(X, y)
```

Comment: `matrix()` works in the column major order by default (values are defined going down each column). It seems that you're trying to define the matrix of coefficients using the row major order (going across rows). Take a look at `byrow` argument to address this.

Comment: thanks man
X = matrix(c(3,2,1,5,4,2,-1,0,-5,2,5,0,1,-1,-5,1),4,4)

y = c(10,5,7,4)

sol = solve(X,y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the argument `byrow` of `matrix()` to `TRUE` does the trick:

```
X <- matrix(c(3, 4,-5, 1,
              2, 2, 2,-1,
              1,-1, 5,-5,
              5, 0, 0, 1), 4, 4, byrow=TRUE)
y <- c(10, 5, 7, 4)
sol <- solve(X, y)
```

Check if correct:

```
c(X %*% sol)
[1] 10  5  7  4
```

By the way, `solve(X, y)` is computationally more efficient than `solve(X) %*% y`.

Comment: X <- matrix(c(3,2,1,5,4,2,-1,0,-5,2,5,0,1,-1,-5,1),4,4)
y <- c(10,5,7,4)
sol=solve(X,y) #equivalent to solve(X,y)
sol

[1]  1.2477876  1.0176991 -0.8849558 -2.2389381

Comment: ive changed the approach to matrix()

this is an exercise of this course
https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:HarvardX+PH525.2x+1T2018/course/